# URL change after sign in and don't show view(no reload, render page) - react

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router-v4

I have a login react class that after passed authentication and successfully authenticated to page should take me to admin page but in this situation it just change URL to admin page after successful sign in or sign out but doesn't show any new admin component at all. I am using react-router v4 and this app don't work with it quite well. Here is My components
Maybe there is any way to solve this problem. I used high order component withRouter that should solve this problem but it doesn't do anything. I have no errors in console.

```
Sign In

import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {reduxForm, Field} from 'redux-form';
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import * as actions from '../../actions/signin_user';


class SignIn extends Component {
    handleFormSubmit({email, password}) {
        this.props.signinUser({email, password});    
    }

    renderAlert() {
        if (this.props.errorMessage) {
            return (
                <div className="alert alert-danger">
                    <strong>Oops! Błąd logowania, kod błędu: {this.props.errorMessage}</strong>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }


    render() {
        const {handleSubmit, fields: {email, password}} = this.props;
        return (
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this))}>
                <fieldset className="form-group">
                    <label>Adres Email:</label>
                    <Field {...email} name="email" type="text" className="form-control" component="input"/>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset className="form-group">
                    <label>Hasło:</label>
                    <Field {...password} name="password" type="password" className="form-control" component="input"/>
                </fieldset>
                {this.renderAlert()}
                <button action="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Zaloguj się</button>
            </form>
        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {errorMessage: state.auth.error}
}

SignIn = reduxForm({form: 'SignIn', fields: ['email', 'password']})(SignIn);

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(SignIn));
```

Admin Page

```
/**
 * Created by konraduciechowski on 26.08.2017.
 */
import React, {Component} from 'react';

import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';


class AdminPage extends Component {
    render() {

        return (
            <div className="header-stick">
                {/*IMPORTANT ADD FUNCTION TO NOT ABLE EVERYONE TO GET TO ADMIN PAGE
                 WHEN THEIR NOT ADMIN*/}
                {/*NEED TO FIX ROUTES FOR ADMIN PAGE*/}
                <ul className="admin-menu">
                    <li className="admin-menu-item">
                        <Link to="/panel+administracyjny/kalendarz">Kalendarz</Link>
                    </li>
                    <li className="admin-menu-item">
                        <Link to="/panel+administracyjny/blog">Blog</Link>
                    </li>
                    <li className="admin-menu-item">
                        <Link to="/panel+administracyjny/pracownik">Zarządzanie pracownikami</Link>
                    </li>
                </ul>

            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default AdminPage;
```

redux action

```
/**
 * Created by konraduciechowski on 16.10.2017.
 */
import axios from 'axios';
import history from '../helpers/history';
import {AUTH_USER, AUTH_ERROR, UNAUTH_USER} from './types'

const ROOT_DEV_API = 'http://salonenface.dev/api/';
const ROOT_PROD_API = 'https://salonenface.pl/api/';
const ROOT_TEST_API = 'http://localhost:3090';


export function signinUser({email, password}) {
    return function (dispatch) {

//Submit password n' email to server
        axios.post(`${ROOT_TEST_API}/signin`, {email, password})
            .then(response => {
                //    if request is good...

                //    Update state to indicate user is authenticated
                dispatch({type: AUTH_USER});
                //    Save JWT token
                localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.token);
                //    redirect to admin route section
                history.push("/panel+administracyjny");
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                ///////////////////////////////////////////
                //    if request is bad...

                //  show error to user
                dispatch(authError(error.response.status));
            })
    }

}

export function signupUser({email, password}) {
    return function (dispatch) {
        axios.post(`${ROOT_TEST_API}/signup`, {email, password})
            .then(response => {
                dispatch({type: AUTH_USER});
                localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.token);
                history.push('/panel+administracyjny');
            })
            .catch(error => dispatch(authError(error.response.data.error)))
    }
}

export function authError(error) {
    return {
        type: AUTH_ERROR,
        payload: error
    }
}

export function signoutUser() {
    localStorage.removeItem('token');
    return {type: UNAUTH_USER}
}
```

EDIT:

Router.js

```
//React imports
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Route,
    Switch,
    Redirect,
    withRouter
} from 'react-router-dom';

//Redux imports
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import promise from 'redux-promise';
import reduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';

//Css imports
import '../styles/App.css';
import '../styles/Admin.css';
import '../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import '../../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css';
import '../../node_modules/react-big-calendar/lib/css/react-big-calendar.css';

//Page Components imports
import Header from './SiteElementsComponents/Header';
import About from './MainComponents/About';
import Blog from './MainComponents/Blog';
import BlogPost from './MainComponents/BlogPost';
import Contact from './MainComponents/Contact';
import Home from './MainComponents/Home';
import Order from './CalendarComponents/Order';
import Services from './MainComponents/Services';
import Login from './AuthComponents/Login';
import Register from './AuthComponents/Register';
import Footer from './SiteElementsComponents/Footer';
import OrderComplete from './CalendarComponents/OrderComplete';
import SignIn from './AuthComponents/SignIn';
import SignOut from './AuthComponents/SignOut';
import SignUp from './AuthComponents/SignUp';

//Admin Components imports
import AdminPage from './AuthComponents/AdminComponents/AdminPage';
import AdminCalendar from './AuthComponents/AdminComponents/AdminCalendar';
import AdminBlog from './AuthComponents/AdminComponents/AdminBlog';
import AdminBlogNewPost from './AuthComponents/AdminComponents/AdminBlogNewPost';
import AdminBlogShowPost from './AuthComponents/AdminComponents/AdminBlogShowPost';
import AdminEmployee from './AuthComponents/AdminComponents/AdminEmployee';
import AuthExample from './TestComponents/AuthExample';

//Redux reducers
import reducers from '../reducers';

//History
import history from '../helpers/history';

//Middleware
const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(promise, reduxThunk)(createStore);

const App = () => {

        return (
            <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
                <div>
                    <div className="col-xs-12">
                        <Router history={history}>
                            <div>
                                <Header/>
                                <div className="container background-block">
                                    <Switch>
                                        <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
                                        <Route path="/o+nas" component={About}/>
                                        <Route path="/aktualnosci" component={Blog}/>
                                        <Route path="/post/:id" component={BlogPost}/>
                                        <Route path="/kontakt" component={Contact}/>
                                        <Route path="/uslugi" component={Services}/>
                                        <Route path="/logowanie" component={Login}/>
                                        <Route path="/signin" component={SignIn}/>
                                        <Route path="/wylogowanie" component={SignOut}/>
                                        <Route path="/signup" component={SignUp}/>
                                        <Route path="/rejestracja" component={Register}/>
                                        <Route path="/wizyta+zapisana" component={OrderComplete}/>
                                        {/*Calendar options*/}
                                        <Route path="/wizyta+zapisana" component={OrderComplete}/>
                                        <Route path="/wizyta" component={Order}/>
                                    </Switch>
                                    {/*test options*/}
                                    <Route exact path="/AuthExample" component={AuthExample}/>
                                    {/*/!*admin options*!/*/}
                                    <Switch>
                                        <Route exact path="/panel+administracyjny" component={AdminPage}/>
                                        <Route path="/panel+administracyjny/kalendarz" component={AdminCalendar}/>
                                        {/*admin blog options*/}
                                        <Route path="/panel+administracyjny/blog" component={AdminBlog}/>
                                        <Route path="/panel+administracyjny/post/nowy" component={AdminBlogNewPost}/>
                                        <Route path="/panel+administracyjny/pokaz+post/:id"
                                               component={AdminBlogShowPost}/>
                                        {/*admin employee options*/}
                                        <Route path="/panel+administracyjny/pracownik" component={AdminEmployee}/>
                                    </Switch>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </Router>
                        <Footer/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </Provider>
        );

}

export default App;
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './components/Router';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import './styles/index.css';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

Comment: can i see your main js file (index.js or app.js)

Comment: I just updated post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You can not pass a history to a `<BrowserRouter>`, as it creates its
>   own history object

If you are creating your own history Object use `<Router>` instead of `<BrowserRouter>` and then pass history object

```
Import { Router } from 'react-router-dom'
<Router history={history}> <Router/>
```

You can read more on [react-router v.4](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4895)

Comment: You are a legend Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help you :)